# Hovering list items with nested divs

Tags: jquery

I'm using an old jquery version, that's why live() is used below.

```
$('#searchresult li').live({
        mouseenter: function () {
            $(this).addClass('active');
        },
        mouseleave: function () {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        }
});
```

My html structure:

```
<ul id="searchresult">
    <li>
         <div>a</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Css:

```
.active { background-color: Red; }
```

My code works in every browser but IE7. The background color flickers, and I guess that's because it only changes when I hover the list element and not the div.

Is there any way to include the divs?

Update:

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yTsw5/3/show/)

Comment: Stop supporting IE7. It's time to move on.

Comment: Use `.delegate()` then it's better than `.live()`,a little bit aside from the topic

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: Any reason you're using jQuery to do that :/? You have `:hover` in CSS too

Comment: you can write this in CSS as well, and should work even > than IE7

Comment: @user1737909 And how would do that. I want the li background to change when hovering the child div as well. Obsiously this doesn't work in Ie7.

Comment: Why not it works just fine it depends on the css

Comment: give us a jsfiddle.net or atleast a screenshot of the problem

Comment: @Johan try using just css `#searchresult li:hover { background-color: Red; }`

Comment: @Johan events should propagate/bubble to the parent/ancestors of the target, so a hover on a child also triggers a hover on the parent.

Comment: @JeffB Doesn't the event only bubble up in the DOM? If it starts at <li> level, the child divs would stay unaffected.

Comment: @Dogoku Updated with fiddle

Comment: @Johan: If you hover the `li`, it should work fine, and if you hover the `div`, the hover event will bubble up to the `li`, unless you have a different handler on the `div` that stops the propagation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are simply modifying the styles, you can just use the [`:hover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/%3ahover) pseudo-class in CSS.

```
#searchresult li:hover {
    background-color: red;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dRyW3/show/)** (jsfiddle "show" view used to support IE7)

**UPDATE:**

Based on your [updated fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/yTsw5/3/show/), I believe this is an issue caused by your [floated elements](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/).

In the following eample, I'm using the [micro clearfix hack](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/). Make sure the clearfix class (`cf` in this case) is added to all of your `searchitem` elements that contain floated children.

**HTML**

```
<li class="searchitem cf">
    ...
</li>
...
```

**CSS**

```
/* For modern browsers */
 .cf:before, .cf:after {
    content:"";
    display:table;
}
.cf:after {
    clear:both;
}
/* For IE 6/7 (trigger hasLayout) */
 .cf {
    zoom:1;
}
```

**[UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2ZWBE/4/show/)**

Comment: @Johan I updated my answer with a new example and information based on your comment.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time. I obviously didn't realse it was a IE clearfix issue.